Under what conditions do distances from pivot points uniquely identify a point on a manifold?
Let $X$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $n$ equipped with a Riemannian metric.
Suppose that $x_1, \dots, x_m$ are pivot points on that manifold. We consider the distance functions
$$
f_i(x) = d( x_i, x )
$$
and thus assign the distance vector
$$
f(x) = \Big( f_i(x) \Big)_{1 \leq i \leq m}
$$
to each point $x \in X$.
Over which subsets $S \subseteq X$ and with how many pivot points is $f$ injective? Note that the pivot points are known and ordered.
I presume that at least $n+1$ are needed on an $n$-dimensional manifold, and $S$ is generally not the whole manifold.

If you only require that there be a non-empty $S\subset X$ on which $f$ is injective, then $n$ points in general position suffice.  For example, two distinct points in the Euclidean plane will give you an injection on either half-plane bounding the line joining the points.  If you want $S = X$, then, generally, you will need more than $n{+}1$ points, but perhaps no more than $2n{+}1$ points. By the way, you might want to let $f_i$ be the square of the distance to $x_i$ so that it will be smooth on a neighborhood of $x_i$.

@RobertBryant  let's consider the  square of  distance instead of  disrance as  you pointed out to. I  wonder can one  prove the  easy or advanced  Withney embedding theorem or  Nash isometric  embedding  theorem via such  function $f$? More precisely: Assume that $(M,g)$ is  a  Riemannian manifold  are there a  finite number of   pivot points for  which the  function $f$ (with square distance)  would  be  an  isometric  embedding? I  did not read the  Nash proof but I  wonder is his proof  based on such  a  function?

+1 for  you  question I think  it generates more questions on some  particular subcategory of  smooth manifolds: For examples what is a  precise example  of  a  symplectic manifold  and  a  finite  even number of  points for which the  square  distance  vector  function f  you mentioned is a  symplectic  embedding?

Any way I vaguely remeber the  square distance  function, distance  to a  set not  to  single point, is introduced as a real analytic  function(in a  book by  S. Krantz whose title  contains  (I thinl) "...real  analytic....". I  do not remenber the reason this function was introduced in his book but  may be his consideration would be  helpful in line of  your  question

Unfortunately, even the squared distance function is not generally smooth on a compact manifold (look at the sphere), it's just smooth away from the cut locus.

@RobertBryant  Thank  you  for  introducing me the cut  locus point. I was not  aware of  it. Are they same  as  focal points (or  any  realtion to it). I think in negative  curvature we have  more  chance for  smoothness of the  squared  distance  function yes?

@AliTaghavi:  In the complete, simply connected, negative curvature case, the squared distance function is smooth, yes.  However, if the surface is completely but not simply-connected, the cut locus will not be empty.

@RobertBryant  Is it a good idea to introduce a generqlized "configuration space" as follows: All n tuples for which the corresponding vector function(squared) is a topological embedding (or in case of empty cut locus case one may consider all n tuple for which the corresponding squared map is isometric or symplectical embedding). In case of negative curvature does it generate a configuration space worth of study?
